# Cookie value undefined in angular 6+

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

i am using angular and node js.
i use "CookieService" package

token.service.ts class

```
 SetToken(token) {
    this.cookieService.set('chat_token', token);
  }

  GetToken() {
     this.cookieService.get('chat_token');
  }
```

trying to use token service in my streams.component.ts but i got undefined in "GetToken"
here is my Streams.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.token = this.tokenService.GetToken();
    console.log(this.token);
  }
```

please help me out to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just forgot to return the token

```
  GetToken(): string {
     return this.cookieService.get('chat_token');
  }
```